# Page numbering according to the chapters

Tags: chapters, page-numbering, scrbook

My lecture notes have the following structure. I would like a page numbering like this : **number of the page in the current chapter / total number of pages in the chapter.**

How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}


\part{Algebra}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\part{Analysis}
\chapter{Chap 1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How should the pages that contain part-level headers be numbered?

Comment: No number for the part-level header ideally.

Comment: Considering how much a role \count0 (\c@page) plays in LaTeX, I would create a new counter for the chepter relative numbers and simply redefine \thepage accordingly.  Note that this will affect \pageref and the TOC, and possibly hyperref.